# Alternatives to cesium terrain builder?

Tags: gdal, dem, software-recommendations, cesium

Looks like `cesium-terrain-builder` still have this [issue](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder/issues/28) and can't be used for large projects, so I wonder if there any alternatives to `cesium-terrain-builder` that can produce DEM tiles, can work with large projects and compatible with cesium?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. We have just released an open source tool called **[tin-terrain](https://github.com/heremaps/tin-terrain)** which is similar but generates optimised irregular meshes (TINs) and can output them as tiles in quantised mesh format directly compatible with CesiumJS

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: I upvoted because Cesium becomes too greed with Ion. I'm very angry with things that stop to work because "now we have an online version. PAY FOR THAT"